# How does the "proxy" field in a create-react-app's package.json work?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have a NodeJS backend running at http://localhost:4050, and I had configured my react application to make API calls to there. For deploying on heroku, I had to change the PORT variable in the backend to be `process.env.PORT`. As a result when I put the react app's `build` folder in the backend's `server` folder, the react application was still searching for localhost:4050 when I deployed to heroku and naturally failed to make calls, because heroku ran the application on an arbitrarily different port. But apparently adding the very same `http://localhost:4050` as `"proxy":"http://localhost:4050"` in the `package.json` file worked. I'm really curious as to how doing that got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

`proxy` field in `package.json` is used to proxy all requests from frontend domain to backend. For example, you have:

- Backend (REST API): localhost:5000/api/user/:id
- Frontend (React.JS app): localhost:3000/user

If you call `axios.get('/api/user/123')`, the browser will send this request to `localhost:3000/api/user/123`, but then react dev server will peoxy it to `localhost:5000/api/user/123`

Please note that this is only for development environment. If you want to deploy your React.JS, there's a better way: https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration

Comment: I'm trying to use the ```build/``` folder (from ```npm run build```), put it into the backend server folder and then deploy the backend to heroku. In that case, how would I have to configure the react application (before make a build version) to make calls to a backend whose exact PORT I do not know until after having deployed it.

Comment: @InfinityIntellect Just use paths without protocol, host and port? `/api/user/123`