# How to use proxy for rest api calls in Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I developed a web app in Mern Stack. Now I'm updating it with Next JS for SEO improvements.

I took some Next JS courses from youtube and read the documentation.

I'm confused about the api folder in the pages folder. the syntax looks like express.

What is it for? Do I have to create my REST Api again in there?

Can I add proxy in package.json for api calls like React in Next JS?

Here is folder structure of the mern app:

```
client
  public
  src
    actions
    components
    constants
    reducers
    screens
    App.js

server
  config
  controllers
  middlewares
  models
  routes
  utils
  server.js
```

Here's an example request to the rest api from client

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getTestimonails = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("/api/testimonials/");

        return await res.json();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };

    getTestimonails().then((data) => {
      setTestimonials(data);
    });
  }, []);
```

Rest API server.js

`app.use('/api/testimonials', testimonialRoutes);`

routes

```
router.route('/').get(getTestimonials).post(protect, createTestimonial);

router
  .route('/:id/')
  .get(checkObjectId('id'), getTestimonialById)
  .put(protect, checkObjectId('id'), updateTestimonial)
  .delete(protect, checkObjectId('id'), deleteTestimonial);
```

Comment: are you serving files from react dev server of from your node.js server in your current project ?

Comment: from react dev server.

Comment: the api folder acts as a server-side program. to be concise, consider it as a program that will be plugged to your dev server seamlessly. so you can either re-create your REST api, or use the one you used because the node js server is independant from your web app (client-side I mean)

Comment: could you show some code to describe the current architecture of your whole project

Comment: both. but especially Mern stack (the current working code)

Comment: nice but please add at least the business logic of requests in your client side and the server.js file (the code)

Comment: updated the question :)

Comment: from what i see, you are not using any proxy. you could just continue to use your backend as it is, keep the client side business logic as it is and rewrite with Next.Js your components only. However, to keep your components clean you should move your getTestimonials to service class with other util functions

Comment: I have added `"proxy": "rest-api-domain"` in react package.json

Comment: It might still work although I never tried since I did never use this proxy option, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/62261689/10707187. I guess it might still work with Next.js